# Problem installing ubuntu 12.04 desktop on sony vaio duo 13

Tags: vaio, sony

I bought new sony vaio duo 13 canadian english keyboard layout with window 8..

I tried more than 5 times installing ubuntu 12.04 using external cd drive. It is not working on sony vaio duo 13. But it working in all other pcs...

I disable safe boot and ubuntu installed in normal mode. But it can't find wireless when starting installation my touch pad also not working during installation process. But i connected internet using lan during installation. During installation it normally open in desktop mode.

After installation complete it open in command prompt only. It is not open desktop environment.

I already updated all packages .. and i also tried re installing ubuntu desktop... i tried every thing... But i am not able to get my ubuntu desktop environment..

Previously i used sony vaio with ubuntu 12.04 desktop.. I want to install ubuntu 12.04 desktop because my website is hosted in ubuntu 12.10 so to develop my website i need ubuntu on laptop..

Please some one help to resolve this problem....Thanks in advance...........

Answer (score -1):

A youtube video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QeNTtn231cU dealing with a vaio pro 13 has the following in the comments:

“I was going to install the current Long-Term Support release of Ubuntu, 12.04 LTS (Precise Pangolin), but as others have noted, this version of Ubuntu has trouble with the wifi hardware on the VAIO Pro. So I ended up using the latest release, 13.10, which supports the wifi.”